# Can fonts be used commercially?

Tags: copyright

If a font comes installed on your computer can you use it commercially? If you use the font do you need to say what font it is? Are fonts copyrighted? (Am I using font wrong? Am I talking about a typeface?)

Comment: To answer the minor nitpick, yes you mean typeface. A font is a combination of all the attributes- size 14 bold Comic Sans is a font, Comic Sans is a typeface.

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7509100/license-of-fonts-included-with-windows

Comment: As a rule of thumb, the copyright status of digital fonts and typefaces is a [hot mess](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intellectual_property_protection_of_typefaces) which varies significantly by jurisdiction. The US has a particularly weird interpretation which protects vector fonts (e.g. TrueType, OpenType, etc.) but probably not raster/bitmap fonts.

Comment: One protection typefaces and fonts do have (at least in the U.S.) is the trademarking of their names.